# unable to send sms using java using sms gateway

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to send sms using java and the sms gateway used is fullonsms.com but its givingg error.Please tell me where did i do mistake.

```
package sms;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class MobileTry 
{
private final String LOGIN_URL    = "http://fullonsms.com/home.php";
private final String SEND_SMS_URL = "http://fullonsms.com/home.php";
private final String LOGOUT_URL = "http://fullonsms.com/logout.php?LogOut=1";

private final int MESSAGE_LENGTH = 10;
private final int MOBILE_NUMBER_LENGTH = 140;
private final int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10;

private String mobileNo;
private String password;
private DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
MobileTry(String username,String password)
{
 this.mobileNo = username;
 this.password = password;
 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
}



public boolean isLoggedIn() throws IOException {
 // User Credentials on Login page are sent using POST
 // So create httpost object
 HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);

 // Add post variables to login url
 List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MobileNoLogin", mobileNo));
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginPassword", password));
 httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

 // Execute request
 try{
 HttpResponse response = this.httpclient.execute(httpost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 if (entity != null) {
     System.out.println("entity " + slurp(entity.getContent(), 10000000));
     System.out.println("entity " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

  return true;
 }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println(e);
 }
 //Check response entity
return false;

}

public boolean sendSMS(String toMobile,String message) throws IOException {
 HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(SEND_SMS_URL);
 List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MobileNos", toMobile));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message", message));

httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
 HttpResponse response = this.httpclient.execute(httpost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 if(entity != null) {
                       System.out.println("entity " + slurp(entity.getContent(), 10000000));
                       System.out.println("entity " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

public boolean logoutSMS() throws IOException {
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(LOGOUT_URL);
 HttpResponse response;
 response = this.httpclient.execute(httpGet);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 if (entity != null) {
  System.out
    .println("entity " + slurp(entity.getContent(), 10000000));
  System.out.println("entity "
    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}


public static String slurp(final InputStream is, final int bufferSize)
{
  final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
  final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
  try {
    final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
    try {
      for (;;) {
        int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (rsz < 0)
          break;
        out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
      }
    }
    finally {
      in.close();
    }
  }
  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    /* ... */
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
      /* ... */
  }
  return out.toString();
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String username = "number";
 String password = "password";
 String toMobile = "number";

 String toMessage = "Message Sent";

 MobileTry fullOnSMS = new MobileTry(username, password);
 try{
  if(fullOnSMS.isLoggedIn() && fullOnSMS.sendSMS(toMobile,toMessage))
  {
   fullOnSMS.logoutSMS();
   System.out.println("Message was sent successfully " );
  }
  System.exit(0);
 }

 catch(IOException e)
 {
     System.out.println(e);
     System.out.println("Unable to send message, possible cause: " + e.getMessage());
 }
}
}
```

following is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.<init>(CloseableHttpClient.java:60)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
    at sms.MobileTry.<init>(MobileTry.java:35)
    at sms.MobileTry.main(MobileTry.java:142)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by missing of `commons-logging-xxx.jar`. Please add it to your classpath. If you use Maven then,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Will add the dependency to your project. Hope this helps!

Comment: you deserve upvoting so I gave and aceeptind your answer too.Can you please tell me this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487628/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-jackson

Comment: Yeah, will check and tell you :)