# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException

Tags: java, android, json, maven, twilio

I am using Twilio to send SMS messages from my web app and I have almost completed the integration. It's sending the SMS, but an error is being generated and I don't understand why. I have included a JSON dependency from this [json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonjar.htm) and this file [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/json/json.jar.zip) but I'm still getting an error. Which other jar do I need to include?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.getParser(TwilioRestResponse.java:225)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.toMap(TwilioRestResponse.java:243)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.SmsList.create(SmsList.java:70)
    at Example.main(Example.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 4 more
```

screenshot showing json added
[image]
**Update this is the new screesnshot**
[image]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39619/discussion-between-naresh-noby-and-javabeginner)

Answer (score 7):

You have missed **jackson-core-asl.jar** 1.9.13 in you project. You can make use of this Maven POM dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this solves your problem. Check this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13) for more information. Direct [link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar) for download

Class is present in the jar Screen below

[image]

Remove your java-json.jar and add the jackson-core-asl.jar

Comment: Can you put the jackson-core-asl.jar in the top above Apache Tomcat 7 by changing its order in order and export of your project.

Comment: I was running in to the same issue when reading parquet files using spark. I downloaded the jackson-core-asl from maven and added it to the spark jars directory which fixed the issue. Thanks and this needs to be accepted as the answer of this question.